# Printer driver issue - install from repository failed Epson Stylus SX425W

Tags: package-management, printing

I have tried to install my printer from the repositories using Synaptic and it failed with the following output:

```
(synaptic:5958): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Selecting previously unselected package libsigsegv2:i386.
(Reading database ... 209196 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsigsegv2_2.10-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libsigsegv2:i386 (2.10-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../dpkg-dev_1.17.5ubuntu5.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.17.5ubuntu5.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package po-debconf.
Preparing to unpack .../po-debconf_1.0.16+nmu2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking po-debconf (1.0.16+nmu2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dh-apparmor.
Preparing to unpack .../dh-apparmor_2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5_all.deb ...
Unpacking dh-apparmor (2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package debhelper.
Preparing to unpack .../debhelper_9.20131227ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking debhelper (9.20131227ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librpmio3.
Preparing to unpack .../librpmio3_4.11.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking librpmio3 (4.11.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librpm3.
Preparing to unpack .../librpm3_4.11.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking librpm3 (4.11.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librpmbuild3.
Preparing to unpack .../librpmbuild3_4.11.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking librpmbuild3 (4.11.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librpmsign1.
Preparing to unpack .../librpmsign1_4.11.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking librpmsign1 (4.11.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rpm-common.
Preparing to unpack .../rpm-common_4.11.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking rpm-common (4.11.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rpm2cpio.
Preparing to unpack .../rpm2cpio_4.11.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking rpm2cpio (4.11.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package debugedit.
Preparing to unpack .../debugedit_4.11.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking debugedit (4.11.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rpm.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/rpm_4.11.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking rpm (4.11.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package alien.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/alien_8.90_all.deb ...
Unpacking alien (8.90) ...
Selecting previously unselected package at.
Preparing to unpack .../at_3.1.14-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking at (3.1.14-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-4.8.
Preparing to unpack .../g++-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking g++-4.8 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++.
Preparing to unpack .../g++_4%3a4.8.2-1ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking g++ (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_11.6ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (11.6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../libfakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:i386 (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../fakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package heirloom-mailx.
Preparing to unpack .../heirloom-mailx_12.5-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking heirloom-mailx (12.5-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.02-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.02-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-2build4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-2build4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsys-hostname-long-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libsys-hostname-long-perl_1.4-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsys-hostname-long-perl (1.4-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmail-sendmail-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmail-sendmail-perl_0.79.16-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmail-sendmail-perl (0.79.16-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpod-plainer-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libpod-plainer-perl_1.03-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libpod-plainer-perl (1.03-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package m4.
Preparing to unpack .../m4_1.4.17-2ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking m4 (1.4.17-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ncurses-term.
Preparing to unpack .../ncurses-term_5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ncurses-term (5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pax.
Preparing to unpack .../pax_1%3a20120606-2+deb7u1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking pax (1:20120606-2+deb7u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-invalid-mta.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-invalid-mta_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-invalid-mta (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-security.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-security_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-security (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-core.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-core_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-core (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-graphics.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-graphics_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-graphics (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-cxx.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-cxx_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-cxx (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-multimedia.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-multimedia_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-multimedia (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-desktop.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-desktop_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-desktop (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-printing.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-printing_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-printing (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-languages.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-languages_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-languages (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking lsb (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package epson-inkjet-printer-nx420.
Preparing to unpack .../epson-inkjet-printer-nx420_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-nx420 (1.0.0-1lsb3.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package man-db (--unpack):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 man-db
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package man-db (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up g++-4.8 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dh-apparmor (2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debhelper:
 debhelper depends on man-db (>= 2.5.1-1); however:
  Package man-db is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package debhelper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.17.5ubuntu5.3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-core:
 lsb-core depends on man-db; however:
  Package man-db is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-multimedia:
 lsb-multimedia depends on lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-multimedia (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-printing:
 lsb-printing depends on lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-printing (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libsigsegv2:i386 (2.10-2) ...
Setting up librpmio3 (4.11.1-3) ...
Setting up libsys-hostname-long-perl (1.4-3) ...
Setting up g++ (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up at (3.1.14-1ubuntu1) ...
atd start/running, process 6483
Setting up libfakeroot:i386 (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.02-3) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-desktop:
 lsb-desktop depends on lsb-multimedia (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-multimedia is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libpod-plainer-perl (1.03-1) ...
Setting up ncurses-term (5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up lsb-security (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Setting up lsb-invalid-mta (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-graphics:
 lsb-graphics depends on lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-graphics (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up build-essential (11.6ubuntu6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb:
 lsb depends on lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-core is not configured yet.
 lsb depends on lsb-graphics (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-graphics is not configured yet.
 lsb depends on lsb-desktop (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-desktop is not configured yet.
 lsb depends on lsb-printing (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-printing is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libmail-sendmail-perl (0.79.16-1) ...
Setting up librpm3 (4.11.1-3) ...
Setting up heirloom-mailx (12.5-2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx to provide /usr/bin/mailx (mailx) in auto mode
Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-languages:
 lsb-languages depends on lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-languages (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up pax (1:20120606-2+deb7u1) ...
Setting up po-debconf (1.0.16+nmu2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up m4 (1.4.17-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-cxx:
 lsb-cxx depends on lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-cxx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of alien:
 alien depends on debhelper (>= 7); however:
  Package debhelper is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package alien (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up debugedit (4.11.1-3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-nx420:
 epson-inkjet-printer-nx420 depends on lsb (>= 3.2); however:
  Package lsb is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-nx420 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up librpmbuild3 (4.11.1-3) ...
Setting up rpm-common (4.11.1-3) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-2build4) ...
Setting up rpm2cpio (4.11.1-3) ...
Setting up librpmsign1 (4.11.1-3) ...
Setting up rpm (4.11.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 man-db
 debhelper
 lsb-core
 lsb-multimedia
 lsb-printing
 lsb-desktop
 lsb-graphics
 lsb
 lsb-languages
 lsb-cxx
 alien
 epson-inkjet-printer-nx420
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the printer driver containing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-ppdc cups-server-common debconf ghostscript libavahi-client3 libavahi-common3 libc-bin libc6 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgcc1 libstdc++6 libusb-1.0-0 lsb-base poppler-utils procps
```

Then open the application `system-config-printer-gnome` and use the printer with it.

Comment: thanks - I ran sudo apt-get update which told me i needed to manually configure dpkg - solved and everything is working now!! :)

Comment: It is better your response towards the answer. thanks. It is much better if you accept the answer by click on the accept button in-front of the answer. So others also can get some benefit from it.